# shell_exec is not working on server

Tags: php, unix, shell-exec, whois

i am using shell_exec to get whois details of a domain. Everything is working fine on localhost but when i am uploading the script on server, it is creating problems. On server, the shell_exec is working partially.

`echo "shell_exec('whoami')";`

gives me an output.

```
mac
```

but when i am using

`echo "shell_exec('whois example.com')";`

I am getting a blank page

Should i consider using a hosting account with root privilege? If yes then how to deal with security issues?

P.S- i dont know if something like this even exists but i've tested it on localhost and it is running fine on MAMP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the issue is with security. Can't you get any logs? But even better, can't you use some high level function in php instead of shell-exec to do the whois!?

Comment: From PHP you do not need to escape to the shell to do a whois query. You have libraries in your programming language or if you want to go to the bottom of it just open a TCP socket to port 43 of the relevant server and send your query followed by CR+LF and just read back a blob of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do decide to host this script with root privileges, then you should (and I'm sorry) be locked up in a padded cell. That's just *mad*! You don't need root privileges to run a simple `whois` command. That's insane!
Hosting as root is about as safe as a nursery, ran by catholic priests, serial killers and crack addicts, who haven't had a fix in three days. Things are going to happen... You can only speculate as to *when* and *how bad* it's going to end.

Check using `whoami` what user is running the script, then check what it's `PATH` looks like, compare that to where `whois` actually *is*, if at all present. If it's not installed, ask your admin to set it up, and give you the rights to use it. If it's installed, try `shel_exec('/path/to/bin/whois example.com');`
Read up on user rights, and environment variables, (and how to load/manipulate them from a PHP script)

Comment: That crack about serial killers was a bit strong wasn't it? :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: If somebody even hints at a bad idea, I think it best to kill it, burn it, and bury it before someone sees it and thinks _"Well, actually..."_. PHP doesn't enjoy the best of reputations, partly because people do things with it that no sane person would ever do. Yes, I was being a little drama Queen, I admit, but I think/hope I made my point about hosting as root

Comment: Hi Elias, the whois command was not installed on the server. Just installed it. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: @AmirNasir: Well than, this answer solved your problem, didn't it? if it did, the SO way of saying thanks is to accept and/or upvote the answer...

Comment: Sure Elias but unfortunately the Voteup requires 15 reputation.
Thanks once again :)

Comment: @AmirNasir: Don't mention it. Always happy to help. Hope I didn't come across as a prat (reading what I've written both in my comments and my answer, I was a bit harsh). Happy coding